# Visual Studio 2015 Edit and Continue duplicates object fields

Tags: visual-studio-2015, roslyn, edit-and-continue

I am experiencing weird issues during Visual Studio 2015 Community debugging a 32-bit C# application (C# 6, .NET 4.5.2) on Windows 8.1 x64.

If I do a couple of Edit and Continue iterations (i.e. break execution, change something, continue), after a while I will get a weird `NullReferenceException` thrown for a field which cannot possibly be null. When I then hover over the `this` instance for the "offending" object, it turns out that there are **multiple fields with the same name** inside that object (and for each pair of fields, one of them with the expected value, the other one `null`). This happened a couple of times already, and wasn't fixed after installing VS2015 Update 1 either.

It seems like a Roslyn issue to me, like it has problems recompiling after Edit and Continue. Is this a known issue that has workarounds?

Comment: Does this seem similar to your issue? https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/issues/4575

Comment: @JeroenVannevel: yes, this looks *exactly* like my issue, thanks a lot, but I have looked through the projects inside and don't think I have auto-generated (wildcard) version numbers anywhere (I wrote I *think* because it's a monogame project, so there are some content-pipeline projects which are not plain old C# projects and don't seem to have a simple version number anywhere). I will check some more to see if I can repro and pinpoint my exact issue. You can add this as an answer because it's certainly helpful.

Comment: Once you found some extra info that can help the Roslyn devs, feel free to  add it as your own answer. I imagine you'll be more on top of this than I am so you can update the post when it gets fixed. Good luck!

Comment: It's been 3 years, both VS2015 Update 3 and VS2017 v15.7.5 are still broken in this way. VS2013 does not have this problem, so to debug my C# code I have to go back to VS2013. Is there really no other solution?